# Extract an attribute value from JSON request when running standalone wiremock server

Tags: json, shell, mocking, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I want to extract an attribute's value from JSON request body coming in a request in a running standalone wiremock server and use the value in the response. Is there any way to this dynamically.

For example, if below is the request body :

```
{
    "name": "Dummy-Name"
}
```

I should be able to extract the value of `name` attribute and send it in the response like below:

`{"Request_Name": "Dummy-Name"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Request model and [JsonPath helpers](http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/#jsonpath-helper) to achieve this.

```
...
    "response": {
        "body": "{ "Request_Name": {{jsonPath request.body '$.name'}} }"
    }
...
```

Note: you will need to enable response templating before this will work.

Comment: Thanks! Also, does it work properly if I use the jsonPath helpers in my response headers as well to send some request body data?

Comment: Also, is it possible to use attribute in the body of one request in another request's response body ?

Comment: `jsonPath helpers in my response headers` -> Yes, it should work the same. `attribute in the body of one request in another request's response body` -> Yes, but you'd need to write a custom response transformer or introduce some of your own custom logic to maintain that state (the request body for A) and return it in the other request (B).

Comment: Is there any link I can refer for writing custom response transformers ?
Also, if I need to introduce some custom logic, where do I need to write that exactly ?

Comment: http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/#response-definition-transformation